# How to get taskbar background color

Tags: .net, windows, taskbar

I have notifyIcon located at the notifyArea of the Win7 taskbar. 
This Icon contain dynamic text info - Black text on the trasparent bitmap.
So, with Standard Windows theme (light) information  readable but with other "dark" windows themes not.

**I want to get taskbar background color and eventually draw Icon with appropriate color (ex White text if Dark taskbar color)**

Comment: So what you're really looking for is the proper text color for an icon in the taskbar, not the taskbar color itself. That's good, because the taskbar can take on the color of a background image; not only will it be impossible to determine but it won't be consistent across the screen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [you are not the first to try](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/ed60ad75-be5c-46c2-87d3-1ea0f5008603).

I think that there are two alternatives, if you don't want a background colour:

1. Add a text border or shadow. You can do that by drawing the text in the border/shadow colour first with a one pixel deviation in the four directions (border) or in the shadow direction.  I suggest a black border around light text.
2. As I understand windows icon support a reverse colour, which is the opposite of whatever colour it is painted on.  Don't look nice but they are pretty visible - I am using them for my cursor.

Hope this helps.